# Have to terminate all the loops according the condition given in inner loop

Tags: ruby

I have five loops as shown below

```
a.each do |i|
  b.each do |j|
    c.each do |k|
      d.each do |m|
        if somecondition.eql?true
         break
       end
     end
    end
    end
  end
```

The above condition terminates only inner loop, Is there anyway can I terminate all the loops?

Comment: As option - move it all to function and use "return"

Comment: You don't have five, you have four.

Answer (score 3):

The standard way is to use `catch` and `throw`.

```
catch :foo do
  a.each do |i|
    b.each do |j|
      c.each do |k|
        d.each do |m|
          if somecondition.eql?true
           throw :foo
         end
       end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The best answer here so far. I never needed this and I was not aware of `catch`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you put all the loops in a method you can break the loops with `return`.

```
def loop_method(a,b,c,d)
  a.each do |i|
    b.each do |j|
      c.each do |k|
        d.each do |m|
          return if somecondition.eql?true
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However loops inside loops inside loops are generally speaking not a great idea. The performance is usually terrible and the code gets tricky to debug/follow. So if there is some way of simplifying things (maybe recursion) that might be a good way to go.

Comment: Can you please explain me how could I use the above loops in the form of recursion?

Comment: I would need more context. where is `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` coming from? what is the purpose of the loop? stuff like that.

Comment: I would if I where you. Start by moving the code to a method. Make sure it worked as is. Then spend a little time to se if I could change it to make it simpler.

Comment: `ncdArray.each do |ncd|
        colorArray.each do |color|
          ncdReasonArray.each do |ncdReason|
    cell("e5")=ncd
    cell("e6")=color
    cell("e7")=ncdReason
   end
  end
end`

This is the small snippet of what I am doing, Can you suggest me now?

Comment: Where does cell come from? but I think a method like `check_ncd(ncd)` is it a and or a or condition?